# Selecting from three tables

Tags: mysql

I am trying to `SELECT` from one table and count from two other tables based on the rows from the first table. I tried the following code below but the rows keep coming empty.

```
SELECT list.id, list.title, list.body, list.poster, list.created_at, count(comments.id) as comcount, count(supports.topic_id) as supcount
FROM (
  SELECT *
  FROM topics
  ORDER BY created_at DESC
  LIMIT 5
) AS list, comments, supports
WHERE
  list.id = comments.id OR
  list.id = supports.topic_id
```

Through in this scenario table `topics` has only two rows and tables `comments` and `supports` have no rows in them, but yet still I should be able to get two rows with their aliases `supcount` and `comcount` each having a value `0` as an output.

I got the solution to the above but am trying something else with the solution provided which I explained in the comment area of the solution provided.

```
SELECT 
t.id,
t.title,
t.body,
t.poster,
t.created_at,
s.supporter,
IFNULL((SELECT COUNT(*) FROM comments c WHERE c.id = t.id), 0) AS comcount,
IFNULL((SELECT COUNT(*) FROM supports s WHERE s.topic_id = t.id), 0) AS     supcount,
CASE WHEN (s.supporter  = "Davies Alex") THEN '1'  ELSE '0' END sup,
CASE WHEN (c.commenter  = "Davies Alex") THEN '1'  ELSE '0' END com
FROM topics t, comments c, supports s
ORDER BY created_at DESC
```

Comment: is this wrong? list.id = comments.id, there may be list_id in comments table no?

Comment: @GeorgeGarchagudashvili am trying to match the `id`'s in list to both `comments` table and `supports` table

Comment: provide you db schema, sample of data and expected result please sqlfiddle would be perfect

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This gonna be working, give a try (using subquery for just counting entries in another table is more suitable):

```
SELECT 
  id,
  title,
  body,
  poster,
  created_at,
  IFNULL((SELECT COUNT(*) FROM comments c WHERE c.id = t.id), 0) AS comcount,
  IFNULL((SELECT COUNT(*) FROM supports s WHERE s.topic_id = t.id), 0) AS supcount
FROM topics t
ORDER BY created_at DESC
LIMIT 5
```

**Update** for new requirement:

```
SELECT 
    t.id,
    t.title,
    t.body,
    t.poster,
    t.created_at,
    s.supporter,
    IFNULL(COUNT(c.id), 0) AS comcount,
    IFNULL(COUNT(s.id), 0) AS supcount,
    SUM(IF(s.supporter IS NOT NULL AND s.supporter  = "Davies Alex", 1, 0)) > 0 AS sup,
    SUM(IF(c.commenter IS NOT NULL AND c.commenter  = "Davies Alex", 1, 0)) > 0 AS com
FROM topics t
LEFT JOIN comments c ON c.id = t.id
LEFT JOIN supports s ON s.topic_id = t.id
GROUP BY t.id
ORDER BY created_at DESC
```

Comment: Supposing I wanted to do something more trickier, for example I wanted to know if a particular `t.id` was supported or commented by a particular user. So am trying something in my new edit. please take a look at it.

Comment: So you want to count comment or supports if `Davies Alex` is the author of the comment/support right? 0 otherwise

Comment: counting the comment and support is separate.The `CASE WHEN` is to determine if ~Davies Alex` has commented or supported that particular topic.

Comment: Thanks men! you an awesome PRO!

Answer (score 0):

In your query, you require `list.id` to either match `comments.id` or `supports.topic_id`. If you use an outer join, you'll be able to retrieve data from the initial table even though the joined tables don't match or contain any data.

```
SELECT
    topics.id, topics.title, topics.body, topics.poster, list.created_at,
    count(comments.id) as comcount,
    count(supports.topic_id) as supcount
FROM lists
LEFT JOIN comments ON comments.id = topics.id
LEFT JOIN supports ON supports.topic_id = topics.id
ORDER BY created_at DESC
LIMIT 5
```